# Unique validation based on presence of datetime attribute, not the value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want a field to be unique based on whether another datetime attribute is present or not.

Something like:

`validates :promo_code, uniqueness: { scope: [:archived_at] }`

PASS:

```
promo_code = TENOFF, archived_at = null

promo_code = TENOFF, archived_at = not null

promo_code = TENOFF, archived_at = not null
```

FAIL:

```
promo_code = TENOFF, archived_at = null

promo_code = TENOFF, archived_at = null
```

Is the only way to do this through a custom validator?

Comment: I think you're correct. You'll have to use a custom validation for this. The `scope` option needs to be an attribute in the database. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, use [`if` or `unless`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless)

```
validates :promo_code, uniqueness: { scope: [:archived_at] }, unless: Proc.new { |o| o.archived_at.blank? }
```

Comment: Nice, this is cleaner and works. Final solution:   validates :code, uniqueness: { scope: [:company_id, :archived_at] }, allow_nil: true, unless: :archived_at

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm doing

```
  validate :unique_code, if: :code

  private

  def unique_code
    return if archived_at.present?
    if self.class.unarchived.where.not(id: id).exists?(code: code, company: company)
      errors.add :code, :invalid
      false
    end
  end
```